# Condicional PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Sou novato em Banco de Dados e precisava de uma ajuda para criação de trigger. Estou fazendo um sistema onde o usuário poderá abrir chamados, criei uma trigger e preciso que ela dispare somente quando o tipo de chamado for ocorrência (no sistema, os tipos de chamados são: ocorrência, denúncia, informação, trote, denúncia, elogio, engano e ligação interrompida).

O ID de ocorrência é 1.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.trigger_fct_tr_atend_tornozeleira()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
 SECURITY DEFINER
AS $function$
declare
latitudeD float8;
longitudeD float8;

BEGIN
  BEGIN  
    BEGIN
    --descricao do estado para inserir na tabela de endereço
    SELECT latitude, longitude INTO STRICT latitudeD, longitudeD
    FROM endereco WHERE ID = NEW.id_endereco;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN no_data_found THEN
      latitudeD = null, longitudeD = NULL;
    END;

    INSERT INTO atend_sac24(
                        id_atendimento,
                        data_criacao,
                        latitude,
                        longitude)
                VALUES (
                        NEW.id,
                        NEW.data_criacao,
                        latitudeD,
                        longitudeD);    

  END;
RETURN NEW;
END
$function$
;
```

Comment: E qual campo representa a ocorrência?

Comment: OI, desculpa a demora. Não entendi muito bem a sua pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa meu querido, tudo bem, segue um modelo do que você deve fazer.

```
 -- drop table if exists chamados cascade;
 -- drop table if exists logs cascade;


create table if not exists chamados (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar(50) not null,
    kind integer not null
  );

create table if not exists logs (
      id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
      text varchar(50) not null,
      data timestamp not null
   ); 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION chamados_log_func()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    -- neste momento eu verifico o tipo do chamado inserido
    -- caso seja do tipo 1 e somente se for verdadeiro é feito
    -- na tabela de logs. aqui sua lógica entra.
    if(new.kind = 1 ) then
        INSERT INTO logs(text, data) values('um chamado',NOW()::timestamp);
    end if;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_log_todos_os_chamados
AFTER INSERT ON chamados
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE chamados_log_func();

insert into chamados(name,kind) values ('teste',1);

select * from logs;
```

É criado duas tabelas, uma de chamados e uma de logs, eu crio uma função e defino ela como trigger para observar as alterações de insert em chamados, caso ela seja do tipo 1, eu faço um log e insiro dentro de logs, agora faça do seu jeito seguindo esta ideia.
As modificações vão além, você poder pegar o Id do chamados como também a horário, enfim customize do seu jeito.

Comment: Entendi. Muito obrigado, vou tentar fazer aqui.
Mas poderia me esclarecer onde eu faria a condicional if dentro do meu código para que somente pudesse ser feito insert e update se o id for igual a 1?

Comment: Esta feito na linha subsequente ao meu begin, veja que faço um e verifico se o `kind` é do tipo '1', caso seja faço o insert na minha tabela de `logs`, ou seja, você deve fazer um if do mesmo jeito e se id do chamado for 1, faça o insert em `atend_sac24`. Verifique a resposta agora.

Comment: Consegui. 
Muito obrigado mesmo pela sua disposição!